# jmeter - Is there any simple way to handle dynamic viewstates when the viewstate count is more?

Tags: jmeter

My request has 3800 viewstates that are coming from the previous request's response. Its very hard to capture the values one by one using reg expression and replacing them with variables.

Is there any simple way to handle them?

Comment: Add more information, sample response and what you are going to do with variables, share your test plan,...

Comment: Can you please clarify.  Do you have one state management variable with 3800 elements  that you are trying to handle individually or is the application returning 3800 distinct viewstate variables for capture.  Both, by the way, represent performance defects which should be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative way of recording a JMeter test using a cloud-based proxy service. It is capable of exporting recordings in SmartJMX format with automatic detection and correlation of dynamic parameters so you won't have to handle them manually - the necessary [PostProcessors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and variables substitutions will be added to the test plan automatically.

Check out [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) article for more details.

---

In general I would recommend talking to your application developers as almost 4k dynamic parameters are too much, it will create at least massive network IO overhead to pass them back and forth and immense CPU/RAM to parse on both sides.